# Rails f.submit (width)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using the following displays a button with a fixed width:

```
f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

However, the next example displays a button with a width equal to its parent container:

```
f.submit 'Submit', class: "btn btn-primary"
```

How can I alter the width of the button in the second example? Adding a width the the CSS class isn't doing the trick.

```
f.submit 'Submit', class: "submit"

.submit {
@extend .btn;
@extend .btn-primary;
width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Did you change default `.btn` css?? Neither of those should have a fixed width using default Bootstrap...

Comment: I have not amended the default bootstrap .btn css.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the rendered html that shows up when you inspect the elements in both cases?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally have the class set to display block which would indeed set it equal to parent container. but if you look at `.btn` [CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/nygR9/) from bootstrap, no where does it specify a fixed with.

Comment: Sorry gents, I'm on my Chromebook and have limited abilities. I will expand with screenshots later.

The second example IS INDEED being rendered via the class. I can alter the color and size by changing from btn-primary to btn-default, etc, etc...

Still not sure why the are rendered with different widths.